# LinkedList insert After node

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I've been trying to insert a node into a linked list after the current node using Java. I've been able to get the insertion before the current node but I cannot get this to work:

Here is the code for `insertNodeBefore`. I just want to know if there is a way to adapt this to be able to insert after the current node?

```
// Insert new node nVal to the list before current node curVal 
public void insertNodeBefore(E nVal, E curVal) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(nVal);

    Node<E> curr = head;
    Node<E> prev = null;

    if (head.getNodeValue() == curVal) {
        newNode.setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // scan until locate node or come to end of list
    while (curr != null) {
        // have a match 
        if (curr.getNodeValue() == curVal) {
            // insert node
            newNode.setNext(curr);
            prev.setNext(newNode);
            break;
        } else {
            // advanced curr and prev
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like newNode.setNext(curr.getNext()); curr.setNext(newNode); ?

Comment: please condider replacing `==` by `.equals()` if you need to find by *value*, not only *reference*.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski it didnt work sorry, it still places it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically find the node and then:

- set the next of new node equals to the current
- set the next of the current to the new node

Something like this should work:

```
public void insertNodeBeAfter(E nVal, E curVal) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(nVal);

    Node<E> curr = head;

    // scan until locate node or come to end of list
    while (curr != null) {
        // have a match 
        // Replaced == with .equals
        if (curr.getNodeValue().equals(curVal)) {
            // insert node
            newNode.setNext(curr.getNext());
            curr.setNext(newNode);
            break;
        } else {
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** is not necessary to have a different treatement for the head because it doesn't change.

Note: could be interesting to handle NOT silently if the list is empty or if the `curVal` is not found, for example throwing a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @mort If the list is empty how do you insert an element "after" another one? It is a design decision, not an error.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO: True. Not checking for `head == null` is a feature in this case, not a bug :)

Comment: @Pat this answer literally duplicates ArturBiesiadowski's comment that you said "didnt work"

Answer (score 3):

I tried to separate traversal code and the insertion code, it is all taken from the supplied code in your question.

```
private void insert(Node<E> prev, Node<E> after, Node<E> newNode) {
    newNode.setNext(after);
    if (prev != null) {
        prev.setNext(newNode);
    } else {
        head = newNode;
    }
}
public Node<E> findPrevOf(E curVal) {
    Node<E> curr = head;
    Node<E> prev = null;
    // scan until locate node or come to end of list
    while (curr != null) {
        // have a match 
        if (curr.getNodeValue() == curVal) {
            return prev;
        } else {
            // advanced curr and prev
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("throw an exception to indicate that value does not exist");
}
public void insertNodeAfter(E nVal, E curVal) {
    Node<E> prev = findPrevOf(curVal);
    Node<E> curr = null;
    if (prev == null) {
        curr = head;
    } else {
        curr = prev.getNext();
    }
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(nVal);
    insert(curr, (curr == null ? curr: curr.getNext()), newNode);
}
// Insert new node nVal to the list before current node curVal 
public void insertNodeBefore(E nVal, E curVal) {
    Node<E> prev = findPrevOf(curVal);
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(nVal);
    insert(prev, (prev == null ? head : prev.getNext()), newNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inserting after a given node is actually easier than inserting before a given node:

```
// Insert new node nVal to the list after current node curVal 
public void insertNodeAfter(E nVal, E curVal) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(nVal);
    Node<E> curr = head;

    // scan until curValnode is found or the end of the list is reached
    while (curr != null) {
        // have a match 
        if (curr.getNodeValue().equals(curVal)) {
            // insert node
            newNode.setNext(curr.getNext());
            curr.setNext(newNode);
            break;
        } else {
            // advanced curr
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: who said that insertNodeAfter needs to add the element if the list is empty?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO: You are right of course. Already fixed it.

Comment: instead of changing the code and make it identical to mine it is better to leave your implementation and briefely describe how it works differently for empty lists.... is not an error also doing that.